# How to bring up a xib as a "pop up" in a ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, interface-builder, xib

I have designed a nice Login box as a xib file in Xcode and when a user taps "Log In" on the landing page on my app, I'd like the Login Box to pop up and let them type in their info.

At the moment though I am having difficulties getting it to show up, as this is my first time working with xibs. Any help would be appreciated. It seems that my IBAction isn't connected because I made a second class, which disconnected the login button from the IBAction. Not sure how to go about fixing that.

Thanks in advance! Using Swift 3 and the latest version on Xcode.

```
import UIKit

class AuthMainViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
}

class loginClass: UIView {

class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "LoginView.xib", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}

@IBAction func loginBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let loginView = loginClass.instanceFromNib()
    self.addSubview(loginView)
    print("Login got pressed")
}
}
```

Comment: As an alternate you can add another View to your ViewController and change alpha values to show it as a pop up. It works beautifully. Isn't it enough for you? Furthermore you can use a Cocoa Library like https://cocoapods.org/pods/DialogView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem with accepted answer is that in only takes care of the view itself, which is not enough to keep UIKit functioning fully correctly.
For having fully functional UIViewController, you should use this:

```
//adding UIViewController to another UIViewController:
addChildViewController(viewController)
view.addSubview(viewController.view)
viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

//removing UIViewController from another UIViewController:
viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Without the other methods you may find malfunctions in many aspect, like:

- appearance methods
- rotation methods
- transition methods
- responder chain
- navigation controller, tab bar controller properties

Reference: 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller

"Implementing a Container View Controller"

> Your container view controller must associate a child view controller with itself before adding the child's root view to the view hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

In your project Pop-up controller is a subclass of UIViewController with a couple of methods you can add view like this:

```
self.popViewController = PopUpViewControllerSwift(nibName: "PopUpViewController", bundle: nil)
self.view.addSubview(popViewController)
```

You can refer to tutorials for how to create  [Pop up window in Swift](http://blog.typpz.com/2015/01/31/ios-sdk-pop-up-window-in-swift/) OR [Adding a subview using a XIB and Storyboard](http://myxcode.net/2015/11/07/adding-a-subview-using-a-xib-and-storyboard/)

Comment: That did the trick! I was actually looking into that as you answered. Thank you.

Comment: But careful !!! - this answer shouldn't be accepted - it's not fully solving the problem. This will make a lot of things not working, since it only takes care of add view itself, not UIViewController. Here appearance methods, rotations methods and few other things won't be working. I will post correct answer separately.

Comment: @Grzegorz krukowski as u said all detail information about how to add view nd all method explain in the provided link.  Than have can you say than my answer is wrong.

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre I did in my answer above, was hard to do as comment

Answer (score 0):

This is what you actually want.

Mainly we can use custom `.xib` to load custom `UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewCell` and Custom PopUp

1. Load Custom .xib as a `UITableViewCell`

Create the pair of custom .xib and its class file something like this.(eg `CustomCell.Swift` and `CustomCell.xib`)

- go to project navigator and on right click create new class with the name of `CustomCell` with the subclass of `UITableViewCell`
- go to project navigator and create new .xib file with the same class name

New File.. -> User Interface -> View -> Save as your class name "`CustomCell`" -> Create

- now you will get the .xib file with the subclass of UIView but we need a `UITableViewCell` so what we will do? we delete that UIView file and add a `UITableViewCell` and give the class name `CustomCell` and Identifier too. (Command + Shift + L) UITableView and drag and drop to the xib window & design cell according your project requirement.
- now we will move to the code part and initialized .xib in our `ViewContoller` Class file and load it in the `UITableView`.
- we will get the cell from our bundle and registered the cell with UITableView.

`UITableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")`

- configured and load the cell in the `cellForRowAt indexPath` with this

`let cell : CustomCell = self.(YourTableView).dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
return cell`

2. Load custom .xib as a `UICollectionViewCell`

Note : Repeat above steps replace `UITableViewCell` with `UICollectionViewCell` and register `UICollectionViewCell` like this

`self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectoinCustCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectoinCustCell")`

- configured and load the cell in the `cellForRowAt indexPath` with this

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : CollectoinCustCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectoinCustCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectoinCustCell
    return cell
}`

- Custom View as a popup (Comes to an end with the appropriate answer for above question)
- create pair of xib file and these time you do not have to remove the UIView from your .xib file.
- get the xib from your bundle like:
- `let CustomXIB = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomXIB", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? CustomXIB`
- Define the frame of your xib file in `viewWillAppear`
- `CustomXIB?.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds`

create the appDelegate instance file to add xib file on main window : your AppDelegate will look like this.

`var AppInstance: AppDelegate!
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {
        AppInstance = self
    }
}`

- and add your customXIB on some IBAction like :

`AppInstance.window?.addSubview(self.CustomXIB!)`

- remove CustomXIB like

`self.CustomXIB?.removeFromSuperview()`